# LINQ to Populate a range

Tags: linq, foreach, range, let

I can't figure out how to do the second part of this (the for/foreach) with a LINQ expressions and haven't found any similar examples with LINQ. rangeDays will be between about 5 and 200, and q1 is a list of MyClasses where RowID is about from 10000 to 25000, without gaps.

```
public class MyClass { public int RowID; public object otherData; }

PopulateRange(int rangeDays, List<MyClass> q1){
var q2 = (from a in q1 
        let Rows = new int[rangeDays]
        select new {a.RowID, Rows }).ToList();
foreach(var a in q2)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < rangeDays; i++)
    {
        a.Rows[i] = a.RowID + i;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

---

Update:
I got this running with 2 linq statements as shown below (hopefully this is all runnable this time).

```
public List<MyClass> PopulateRange(int rangeDays, IQueryable<TheirClass> q1)
{
    var q2 = (from a in q1 
                select new MyClass()
                { RowID = a.RowID, Rows = new int[rangeDays] }).ToList();
    q2.ForEach(a => a.Rows = Enumerable.Range(0, rangeDays).
                Select(i => i + a.RowID).ToArray());
    return q2;
}
public class MyClass
{
    public int RowID;
    public int[] Rows;
}
public class TheirClass
{
    public int RowID;
    public int ID;
    public string Symb;
    public DateTime? EventTime;
    public decimal? Value;
}
```

This is acceptable, but does anyone know why the following single statement throws a NotSupportedException "Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query operators except the Contains operator." when I try to compile & run:

```
public List<MyClass> PopulateRange(int rangeDays, IQueryable<TheirClass> q1)
{
    var q2 = (from a in q1 
                select new MyClass() 
        { RowID = a.RowID, Rows = Enumerable.Range(0, rangeDays).
        Select(i => i + a.RowID).ToArray() }).ToList();
    return q2;
}
```

Comment: Something isn't quite right. `q1` is supposed to be a `List<int>`, so how does an `int` have a `RowID` property?

Comment: ... and where does "Rows" come from?

Comment: @Jon Skeet: `Rows` is introduced by the `let` clause.

Comment: Ok, I updated the OP because q1 was not a list and that clearly confused the issue. Also because of how the "=" works my original post was leaving all rows with the same values.

Answer (score 2):

A slight variation on Ani's answer:

```
var q2 = q1.Select(a => new { Rows = Enumerable.Range(a.RowID, rangeDays)
                                               .ToArray(),
                              RowID = a.RowID });
```

Differences:

- When there's just a single select, I don't bother with query expression syntax
- Rather than using Range from 0 and then Select, I figured it would be easier to just start off at a.RowID :)

Comment: +1: While both of what you mention are true, I was trying to do a 'literal' conversion of the OP's code, especially the loop.

Comment: You are both correct, I had a class (new { int, object}).
Right now I am getting "NotSupportedException  
The query operator 'Range' is not supported. 
Message The query operator 'Range' is not supported."
That is in LinqPad though. I'll set up a run in VS sometime soon.

Comment: @Gary: That's pretty odd... but then I've just noticed you're trying to get a `RowID` from an `int` according to your original code, so there must be something you're not telling us... is `q1` actually a database query?

Answer (score 0):

I think `q1`'s type should actually be `List<MyRowClass>` or similar (it certainly can't be a `List<int>`).
You probably want:

```
var q2 = (from a in q1
          select new
          {
              a.RowID,
              Rows = Enumerable.Range(0, rangeDays)
                               .Select(i => i + a.RowID)
                               .ToArray()

          }).ToList();
```